# Ordnance Survey to obj or fbx

Tags: ordnance-survey, blendergis

I would like to download some elevation data (DEM) from Ordnance Survey and then import it into something like Blender.

Ordnance Survey data comes in two flavours: GLM 3 and ERSI Shapefile.

How can I convert either of those formats to a format that is supported by Blender?

Comment: use the OS Terrain 50 https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/terrain-50.html (not panaroma dataset as old and fragmented like broken contours)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163611/contour-lines-with-imported-shape-file-using-blender-gis-wrong-z-values).

I've used [Blender GIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) to import SHP files and it works pretty well.

Blender GIS can import SHP files and make a Delaunay triangulation so you can have a surface from contour lines. Also, there is an addon that opens Open Street Maps on Blender!

Just notice some details, like, for example, your SHP can't have NULL values.

I've not tried point SHPs tough, but it should work.