# Import DEM in blender as mesh

Tags: qgis, blendergis

First of all, I want to apologize because I am a beginner in this area and not a native English speaker, so sorry if I ask simple questions or if I am hard to understand.

So I have DEM files in the form of ASC files representing squares of 5 km and a resolution of 5 m (so 1 million points/file). What I want to do is import them in Blender to edit them and study them. I am able to convert the ASC files to TIF files and import them to as points cloud with the BlenderGIS plugin but then I need to skin them with a plugin which make mistakes and the files are far too large to be corrected manually. The other method i tried was to import the file in Blender "As DEM" and it work great but when I switch to edit mode, the mesh is flat and I cannot edit it the way I need. Do you see any method or tool that I can use to help me ?

As I said, I am a real beginner and I may have missed something obvious so if you think of anything please try to help me !

Comment: If you speak french, you can have a look here, the creator of BlenderGIS gives some tips  : https://georezo.net/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=249485#p249485

Comment: Okay, thank you. The site seems unreachable for now but I'll take a look as soon as I can.

Comment: I've emailed the BlenderGIS developer once (in english) and he answered and solved my problem (it was a bug actually). There is also the BlenderGIS Github page : https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS

Answer (score 3):

You can:

1. Load the DEM into [QGIS](https://qgis.org/)
2. use the QGIS tool to draw contour lines based on the DEM ([tutorial here](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/working_with_terrain.html))

[image]

3. save the contour lines as a SHP (shapefile)
4. import the SHP in Blender using BlenderGIS
5. also using BlenderGIS, make a [TIN](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS/wiki/Make-terrain-mesh-with-Delaunay-triangulation) (triangular irregular network) using the Delaunay function. Then, you will have your terrain as a mesh.

[image]

For more info, see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163611/contour-lines-with-imported-shapefile-using-blender-gis-wrong-z-values/164414#164414).

Hope it helps.