# Why does Blender not accept DT2 file (elevation data from EarthExplorer)?

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, blendergis

Trying to do the Creating Shaded Relief in Blender tutorial

https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/creating-shaded-relief-in-blender/

Got the file from SRTM 1 Arc-Second Global. Got also a DEM file from NASA STRM3 STRMGL30 and Blender does not read it. The file does not appear in Blender's file opener.

Comment: You write DT2 file in the question topic, but I doubt Blender can read those. Reading the tutorial that you are linking, there is quite a long process of preparation for the DEM-raster (here: https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/blender-relief-tutorial-getting-set-up/). Did you go through these steps and convert the DEM to a integer TIF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

1. Under QGIS save the raster as GeoTIFF from `Raster` -> `Conversion` -> `Translate (convert format)...`. This is actually an interface to the underlying `gdal_translate`.
2. *(optional)* Open the GeoTIFF in GIMP or Photoshop
3. *(optional)* Save the file as simple TIFF
4. Open in Blender

**Screenshot of the `gdal_translate` interface.**

Make sure you select `UInt16`.

[image]

From https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/blender-relief-tutorial-getting-set-up/ the important excerpt:

> Once you’ve got the DEM reprojected, clipped, and rescaled, it’s time
>   to save it as a 16-bit unsigned TIFF.  ... If you’re in QGIS, you’ll
>   need to Translate and manually add the -ot tag to the GDAL output to
>   specify the data type (UInt16).
>
> (Possible) Step Eight: Re-Save I have no idea if this is true for
>   QGIS, but ArcGIS, at least, saves TIFF files that Blender can’t read
>   directly. Not sure why. But, if you open the TIFF in Photoshop, then
>   Save as a new file, Blender will be able to read that new file.
>   Passing it through Photoshop seems to clean it up somehow; other image
>   editing programs may fix this problem, too.

Comment: Blender still does not read the file even I use the Translate in QGIS and export it again as TIF via GIMP. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: This might be obvious: does the file have a .tif extension? Could you post the exported file somewhere?

Comment: Yes. It's a TIF file. https://i.imgur.com/1YA9zru.png

Blender still does not read it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use QGIS (which is open source) and/or Blender plugin [Blender GIS](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS).

Using QGIS, you can make a SHP (shapefile) out of a DEM and with Blender GIS you make a mesh out of the SHP (see [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/283688/import-dem-in-blender-as-mesh/283927#283927) and [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163611/contour-lines-with-imported-shapefile-using-blender-gis-wrong-z-values/164414#164414)), or, you can import SRTM directly into Blender using only Blender GIS.

[image]