# Import 3D Shapefile in AutoCAD

Tags: 3d, import, autocad, 3d-map, autocad-map

I have a shp containing polygons with ELEVATION attribute field. I want to import it to Autocad and display it as 3D polygons based on the ELEVATION field without using SOLID or SURFACE in acad .
I've seen that "Spatail Manager" *(http://www.spatialmanager.com/spm-forautocad/)* gives a solution **but** with cost of payment.
is it possible to do it with Autocad only ?

This video shows what I'm looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dzSNkOBtQnU&t=2s

-I'm using AutocadMap3D 2018.

Comment: Are there too much polygons so that you can't export as DXF and manually adjust the elevation in AutoCAD?

Comment: No, the amount of polygons is not the problem. The point is that I don't want to manually adjust the elevation, I want Autocad to display the polygons automatically (with their thick and hight geometry) when I import them as shapefile.

Comment: Is AutoCAD your only option or just a tool to achieve something in 3D? See this question (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163611/contour-lines-with-imported-shapefile-using-blender-gis-wrong-z-values), it uses Blender + Blender GIS. And I think it is possible to import a SHP into Blender with height and thickness. Maybe after that, Blender can export a format that AutoCAD can read. EDIT: looking at the video, are you dealing with buildings? If so, the Blender GIS I've cited does just that with OSM data.

Comment: Marcos,thank you.  Yes the polygons are buildings but Autocad is my only option...