# Problems when importing shapefile with the Blender GIS add on from QGIS: contour lines appear flat

Tags: qgis, shapefile, contour, blendergis

So I'm trying to import a shapefile of contour lines of groundwater isohypses that I have loaded into QGIS and saved separately. I'm actually following the steps of a online tutorial of our department so it is really strange that things don't work out like they supposed to.

The Shapefile has ELEV data that can be checked within the attribute table but when clicking the relevant boxes in the Blender GIS Add On (Elevation->Field->ZLevel (the name of the ELEV data field)) the Result looks like this:

[image]

[image]

The contour lines seem to be "stuck" to the 0 Z-level.

I checked this question in the forum and tried all the things that this person did but it didn't change the result: [Contour lines with imported shapefile using Blender GIS - wrong Z values](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163611/contour-lines-with-imported-shapefile-using-blender-gis-wrong-z-values)

...is there any parameter that I oversee?

Interestingly, when I work with other contour line shapefiles, or different CRS (I tried both WGS Web and local CRS - according to the tutorial it isn't relevant to transform the shapefile to a WGS CRS if you only work with your own data in Blender) the result also isn't satisfying and looks like the line levels are exploded or stacked:
[image]

Is it a bug like in the other question or is it a mistake I'm doing?